# How to exclude other devices depending on their screen size in Android?

Tags: android, size, screen

I am using the code below to exclude other devices according to their screen size, but how would you know which one is which. Is Droid X and Droid Bionic is considered normal screen or large screen? And how about Android Tablet is it Large Screen Or XLargeScreen?

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable=["true"| "false"]
                  android:smallScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:normalScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"]
                  android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="integer"
                  android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
                  android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) a nice document that will clarify which device belongs to which group. Hope this helps.